# Obtain the window object from a variable pointing to document

Tags: javascript, window, document, parent

If I have

```
var doc=window.document;
```

and I don't want to define another variable, how can I refer to `window`?
`doc.parentNode` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.defaultView` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.defaultView) should work, but of course not in IE (until IE9). But it seems you can use `document.parentWindow` there.

So cross-browser would be:

```
document.defaultView || document.parentWindow
```